# Caching a value or calling function - what is better?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am not sure what is better between the following two versions of code:

```
var getKey = function(e) {
    return e.keyCode || e. which;
}; 


function doSomething() { 
   if(getKey(e) === 32 || getKey(e) === 9 ) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

OR

```
function doSomething() { 
   var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
   if(key === 32 || key === 9 ) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

How do we measure performance? Does the speed of execution determines if the performance is good or not OR is it the amount of memory that the application uses?

Thanks

Comment: Plug both of those into JSPerf and see which one is faster. Neither one is a memory issue.

Comment: This is a micro optimization. Don't do it, it's the root of all evil in this case. Write the more readable code.

Comment: @Mathletics Thank you for mentioning JSPerf.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thank you. As a beginner its sometimes difficult to know what is worth how much. But discovering great tools like JSPerf will surly make things easier to learn.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that calling a function will be very much slower, however that is irrelevant in choosing which to use as you're talking nanoseconds.

Comment: @LuckySoni No! JSPerf is _very_ easy to misuse. Just don't worry about performance in these tiny little scenarios. How many times is the keyboard being hit and the event is fired? Is it less than 10000 times per second? Good, then it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum ok thanks i wont use JSPerf for such tests but just out of curiosity how do you know that its not going to make a difference even if the event occurs 10000 times? How do you test for this or did you take someone else's word as i am going to do now? If possible i want to see it with my own eyes before i believe it (no insult intended and i am 100% sure that what you speak is correct, i just like to experience what my code does and then learn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not going to really ever be a performance comparison to make here. Performance issues arise when something is happening multiple times per millisecond and they need to be optimized.

That is not that case here. The information for the key is going to be coming from an event. Events are not caused very often (at least not when compared with millisconds) and so any sort of approach to optimization will not have any benefit.

Comment: What if i am creating a game and trying to bind the keydown event which i think is going to pressed thousands of time during a single gameplay? But now i can check on JSPref so i am hoping i'll get an answer to it there.

Comment: @LuckySoni - A thousand times during a single gameplay is rather insignificant. It is an O(1) operation to determine the key, and even if the event were on keydown and the user held down the key there would be no noticeable difference between the two. Metrics like path finding and collision detection are what add up quickly in games, not key detection.